# Boolean column returns nil when called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When calling

```
pry(main)> User.where(is_validated: false).first.is_validated
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_validated" = 'f' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

The model in question does exist and has a value of `false` for is validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that to get the value from a boolean field on an active record model you NEED to end it with a question mark, which will return a boolean on any column

```
pry(main)> User.where(is_validated: false).first.is_validated?
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_validated" = 'f' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> false
```

I might have missed it but I haven't seen this "feature" documented anywhere else.

EDIT: However, it does seem to work without the question mark when said column is delegated.

```
Outlet.first.is_national
  Outlet Load (34.9ms)  #...
  Location Load (51.5ms)  #...
=> true
```

Comment: If someone can find where this is documented in a sanely located place (without diving into the source and accessible from Google with relatively obvious search terms) I'll happily award them the green check.